# Niceform jquery Dropdown change event change not working

Tags: jquery, onchange, html-select, niceforms

Niceform jquery Dropdown change event change not working my code is is here

```
<select style="width:1px;" class="NFhidden" size="1" id="aics_Enquiry" name="aics_Enquiry">
    <option value="0">General enquiry</option>
    <option value="1"> Request a statement</option>
    <option value="2"> Feedback</option>
    <option value="3"> Other</option>
</select>
```

And resulted code in html is here.

```
 <div class="NFSelect" style="width: 5px; left: 767px; top: 593px; z-index: 999;"><img src="/templates/liberty/images/0.png" class="NFSelectLeft">
 <div class="NFSelectRight">Feedback</div>
 <div class="NFSelectTarget" style="display: none;">
 <ul class="NFSelectOptions">
 <li><a href="javascript:;">General enquiry</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;">Request a statement</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;" class="NFOptionActive">Feedback</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:;">Other</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 <select style="width:1px;" class="NFhidden" size="1" id="abc" name="abc">
 <option value="0">General enquiry</option>
 <option value="1"> Request a statement</option>
 <option value="2"> Feedback</option>
 <option value="3"> Other</option>
 </select>
```

Change event is not working as my jquery code is here for change event

```
$("#abc").change(function(){
// Code implementation  in change event
});
```

But it is not working because here select html tag is not change. selected and selected
item is converted in div tag.

How to work with dropdown change event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your jquery should be:

```
$(document).on('change', '#abc', function(){
     // code
});
```

use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to target elements generated dynamically or created after the page loads.